# How do I pass a custom parameter to nextjs dynamic route so I can access it inside getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to pass an ID as a custom parameter to `next/link <Link />` and be able to access it inside getInitialProps. I want to use clean URL's but the API i'm using only allows you to query it via the post ID. So while I can access the post slug inside getInitialProps I cant use it to query the post.

I currently have it set up to use the post slug in the URL

```
<Link href="/article" as={`/article/${urlPattern}`}>
    <a>{title}</a>
</Link>
```

and in getInitialProps I can access the slug via the context parameter

```
Article.getInitialProps = async context => {
    const slug = context.query;
    // need query ID
    // do api call
};
```

Is there a way I can pass the ID to  so I can access it inside getInitialProps via the context to do my API call?

** **EDIT** **

I've updated the  by adding a query property which allows me to access the id via context.query.id but doing so also updates the page URL to /article/the-article-title?id=234234324324 I dont want the URL to include the article id just the article name but I still need a way to access the article ID inside getInItialProps so I do the api call.

```
<Link
    href="/article/[article]"
    as={{
        pathname: `/article/${urlPattern}`,
        query: { id: system.id }
    }}
>
```

Comment: does the slug contain id?

Comment: No the slug is just the title of the post

Comment: have you tried passing an url object like in the example https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-url-object-routing/pages/index.js?

Comment: Yes the issue is I cant access these objects inside getInitialProps

Comment: unfortunately if you the server side does not provide a way to fetch post via slug then it is not possible. better to update server to support fetching by slug

Comment: Yes you're right i've going to update to support slugs thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an [URL object](https://nextjs.org/docs#with-url-object) to the `as` prop:

```
<Link
      href={"/article"}
      as={{
        pathname: "/article",
        query: { id: "query id" }
      }}
    >
      <a>title</a>
    </Link>
```

There is an example: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-url-object-routing

Comment: I can't access this inside getInitialProps

Comment: @user3486427 would you be able to create a codesandbox with a demo? something similar to https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-pond-xtwww

Comment: This works but the url ends up like this
/article/coffee-beverages-explained?id=cf106f4e-30a4-42ef-b313-b8ea3fd3e5c5
which is not ideal. Is there a way to pass the id without updating the url?

Comment: @user3486427 are you using `next export` to generate static pages? (one html for every article)